# Getting error in logstash while pushing data into Elasticsearch using amazon_es plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to push data into Amazon Elasticsearch using Logstash. But getting the error -

```
Error while performing resurrection {:error_message=>"undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass", :class=>"NoMethodError", :backtrace=>["/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.11.32/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb:45:in `initialize'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-6.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client/manticore_adapter.rb:108:in `perform_request'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-6.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client/pool.rb:291:in `perform_request_to_url'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-6.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client/pool.rb:245:in `block in healthcheck!'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1343:in `each'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-amazon_es-6.4.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client/pool.rb:241:in `healthcheck!'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:234:in `block in start_resurrectionist'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:128:in `until_stopped'", "/etc/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.1.1-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client/pool.rb:233:in `block in start_resurrectionist'"]}
```

Logstash version - 6.2.4
Elasticsearch version - 6.5

Config is given below -

```
amazon_es
  {
               id => 'es-bag-prod'
               hosts => ["https://${ES_HOST}:${ES_PORT}"]
               region => "ap-southeast-1"
               aws_access_key_id => "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
               aws_secret_access_key => "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
               timeout => 25
               index => "${ES_INDEX_PREFIX_BAG}-%{[@metadata][month]}"
               document_type => "${ES_BAG_DOC}"
               document_id => "%{[@metadata][doc_id]}"
               action => "%{[@metadata][action]}"
               version => "%{[@metadata][version]}"
               version_type => "external_gte"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting Logstash? It seems that there maybe issues with access to the env variables when running Logstash as a service. See this for more info:

https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/issues/34

Comment: As given in this link, there is no file /opt/logstash/bin/logstash

Comment: What is "as given in this link"? The file doesn't need to be in that exact location, that's where the poster in that thread has Logstash installed. So how are you starting? Via the logstash executable, where you may have that installed, or as a service? Did you try to setup the env variables?